# unordered map with "external" key storage

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a `std::unordered_map(key,pos)` and a (self implemented) `binary_heap(key,value)`

Now the unusual thing is that my keys are fixed size integer arrays and the pos is just an integer (the position in the binary heap (the heap is given in an vector representation)), val is also just an integer which is some distance value.

currently the heap as well as the unordered_map both have an object for the key.
So every key that is inserted exists twice (once in the map and once in the heap).

Is there a nice way to store the "key objects" in a vector and then just accessing them from the heap and map.

Note that the number of considered elements (keys) is very large and the number of possible keys is not known.

Comment: Please edit your question to show actual code instead of prose.